# Put a field in views with the vocabulary of the taxonomy term from a contextual filter

Tags: views

I have a view which accepts taxonomy terms as contextual filters.
Now, what I would like to have is to put the vocabulary of the term in a field. Relationships?...
On the nodes that arewhown by views there are two fields with taxonony terms, and the view can be sorted by both. I want to access the *very one* the view is filtered with.

Comment: Is it a node view or a taxonomy view?

Comment: this is a node view, (ie, a view of nodes), filtered by tax terms

Answer (score 0):

Add a `term relationship` based on the term field.

[image]

Then add a `taxonomy Vocabulary Name` Field using that relationship.
[image]

Comment: The thing is the node there are two fields with taxonony terms, and the view can be sorted by bot, and I want to access the very one the view is sorted with.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a field in views with taxonomy vocabulary name then there is no need to use relationship. While creating a new view just select -

**Show -> Taxonomy Terms**

But if you want to show other content fields with that view then use relationship -

**Taxonomy term: Content with term**

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear: I need to access the vocabulary of the term that is being used for filtering.